# Returning the 'predictions' from Tensorflow.js Text toxicity detection model

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm currently trying to implement a comment section on the website I created for University.
My goal is to check if a comment is toxic or not followed by an alert or publishing the comment.
I'm using the pretrained model from Tensowflow.js.
Now I struggle with returning the 'predictions'-array, so I can check if the model returns a toxic classification or not.

```
//Model laden
toxicity.load(grenzwert).then(model => {
    //Kommentar als modelinput
    var saetze = kommentar;
    var modeloutput = new Object();

    //Vorhersage
    model.classify(saetze).then(predictions => {
        modeloutput = predictions;
        return modeloutput;
    });
    //Vorhersage übergeben
    console.log(modeloutput);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to `await` the result of the prediction

```
modeloutput = await model.classify(saetze)

console.log(modeloutput);
```

The only thing to keep in mind is that `await` needs to be in an async function

Comment: Thank you very much sir. You were a great help!